# JSON into HTML with Angular.js using ng-shodown

Tags: angularjs, json, markdown

What do I need to pass to *makeHtml()* in the directives.js to get converted my JSON into HTML?

I've been reading all the documentation and didn't get anything clear. I'm using angular.js 1.6.4 and included 'ngSanitize','ng-showdown' in my app.js dependencies.

pages.json

```
[
  {
    "title" : "Home"
  },
  {
    "title" : "About",
    "content" : "#Hello markdown!"
  },
  {
    "title" : "Contact",
    "content" : "Contact content"
  }
]
```

page.html

```
<markdown-to-html>{{page.content}}</markdown-to-html>
```

directives.js

```
angular.module('app.directives', [])
  .directive('navigationbar', [function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      templateUrl: 'views/_partials/navigationbar.html',
      controller: ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('data/pages.json').then(function(data) {
          $scope.pages = data;
        });
      }]
    }
  }])
  .directive('markdownToHtml', [function(){
    var converter = new showdown.Converter();
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      html: converter.makeHtml(???????????????)
    }
  }]);
```

The most I get is undefined...

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you are injecting the `ngSanitize` dependency

```
angular.module('app.directives', ['ngSanitize'])
```